# How to configure Minimum Cost Maximum Flow to solve Unbalanced Assignment Problem?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, network-flow

### Problem

$n$ objects have to be assigned to $m$ categories, with $n \ge m$. Assigning an object $i \in [n]$ to a category $j \in [m]$ comes with a cost $c_{ij}$. Multiple objects can be mapped to the same category. All objects have to be assigned. All categories have to be used.

### What I tried

Since it seems to be a special case of the Unbalanced Assignment Problem, I looked towards the Hungarian Algorithm. Unfortunately, the way this algorithm deals with unbalanced bipartite graphs does not  seem to help much here - although I'm still looking in the litterature for an adequate extension, maybe [here](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2012/HPL-2012-40.pdf).

So I tried to map this problem to the Minimum Cost Maximum Flow Algorithm, but despite trying some parametrizations of the edges capacities, I can never guarantee that all the jobs are actually assigned and that all machines used.

For example, in the following picture all the $n=8$ objects (right set of vertices) could be assigned to a category, only 2 of the $m=3$ categories were used, what is not what I want.

[image: bipartite graph incomplete assignment]

### Question

Is it possible to achieve the desired result under some specific configuration of the Minimum Cost Maximal Flow algorithm, or am I looking to the wrong algorithm?

Comment: @MikeEarnest thanks for the feedback, I updated the question to the best I could - but if I missed important information feel free to mention it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $c_i^* = \min_{j \in [m]} c_{ij}$ be the minimum cost of assigning object $i$ to *any* category. If not for the constraint that all categories must be used, we would have a solution with cost $C^* := c_1^* + c_2^* + \dots + c_n^*$ just by giving each object its best category.

To satisfy that additional constraint, consider the matching problem where each category must be assigned an object (but not all objects have to be assigned), and the cost of assigning object $i$ to category $j$ is $c_{ij} - c_i^*$. (Think of this as the cost of "reassigning" object $i$ away from its best category.) This is equivalent to the original problem for the following reason:

- Suppose we solve the new problem. Extend this solution to solve the original problem, by giving each unassigned object its best category. Passing to the original problem, each object's cost increases by $c_i^*$, and so the total cost increases by $C^*$.
- Suppose we have an optimal solution to the original problem. Each category $j$ then contains at most one object $i$ such that $c_{ij} > c_i^*$ (if there are two such objects, we can reassign one of them to its best category and improve the cost). Pick such an object for each category; if a category contains no such objects, pick any object that's been assigned to that category. The result is an assignment of one object to each category, which is a solution to the new problem with total cost decreased by $C^*$.

Therefore if we solve the new problem optimally, we can get an optimal solution to the original problem.

---

How can we solve the new problem optimally? There are a few methods:

1. Create $n-m$ new categories for the new problem such that the cost of assigning any object to any of the new categories is $0$. Then, apply the Hungarian algorithm. Finally, forget the new categories we added.
2. Solve a minimum-cost flow problem where the source has a cost $0$ arc to each category, category $j$ has a cost $c_{ij}-c_i^*$ arc to object $i$, and each object has a cost $0$ arc to the sink. All arcs have capacity $1$. A flow of value $m$ with minimum cost (equivalently, a minimum-cost maximum flow) is exactly the matching we want.
3. I'm pretty sure that with this modification, the linked article "On Minimum-Cost Assignments in Unbalanced Bipartite Graphs" does exactly what we want.

Comment: Wahooo. This is a very complete response! I will go with solution 2 since it's the one that is the closest to my current implementation! :)

Comment: *Extend this solution to solve the original problem, by giving each unassigned object its best category*: I think this is subobtimal unless I misunderstand something. 
Assuming that for all unassigned objects $i$, their minimal cost $c_i^* = \min_{j \in [m]} c_{ij}$ maps to the same category $j$, then the assignment will be "overflowing" this category (for a lack of better words)

Comment: How can this be suboptimal ? There's no better category they can get! Or did I misunderstand "Multiple objects can be mapped to the same category"?

Comment: :) Multiple objects can be mapped to the same category, but there is still a cost associated to it. It's like trying to fill empty buckets of different volume (categories) using many water jars of different volume (objects). You have to use all the water, each bucket has to receive at least one jar of water, and the cost is how close you come to right level, meaning you get penalized if a bucket is too empty, and you also get penalized if a bucket is overflown. With the current solution, I get all the unassigned jars left go to the same bucket, overflowing it. Is it expected?

Comment: note: the same bucket is overflown, but others are left way too empty, if it makes sense.

Comment: If there is an additional penalty associated to having multiple objects in the same category, then you have to include such things in the problem statement. (The individual object-to-category cost *is* already included.)

Comment: So you are saying that the problem I described in terms of buckets/jars is not the same as the one I described in my initial question? :'(

Comment: I think so, though I'm not entirely sure. An example: let $n=10$, $m=3$, and let $c_{i1}=1$, $c_{i2}=2$, $c_{i3}=3$ for all $i$. My algorithm might match objects $1,\dots,8$ to category 1, object 9 to category 2, and object 10 to category 3. This minimizes the sum of $c_{ij}$ over all pairs $(i,j)$ used by the matching: it is $8\cdot 1+2+3$, and you can't do better. If you want to split them more evenly (say, 4 objects to category 1 and 3 to each of categories 2, 3), the sum of $c_{ij}$ goes up to $4\cdot1+3\cdot2+3\cdot3$; you want a different objective for this to be a better solution.

Comment: Maybe consider minimizing the maximum value of $$\operatorname{load}(j) := \sum_{i : (i,j)\in M} c_{ij}$$ over all categories $j$? This still allows different categories to match different objects better, while trying to spread out objects between all categories as much as possible.

Comment: I think I found the solution to this problem in [this paper](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs498dl1/sp2015/notes/25-maxflowext.pdf), where the general problem to allow each edge to specify a lower bound on its flow value (in addition to an upper bound/capacity) is casted to a maximum flow problem on a modified graph structure.